# What formula checks to see if a sequence of cells exists in a range?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets file, containing two pages. The first is "Current Combinations", which has a list of already-created items in it. The second is "All Combinations" shows all possible combinations of items.

I want to figure out what kind of formula I'd use to identify whether a sequence in "All Combinations" exists in "Current Combinations".

Ideal end result:

---

"Current Combinations.gsheet"

"Dull", "Blue", "Cockatiel"

"Bright", "Blue", "Parrot"

---

"All Combinations.gsheet"

"Bright", "Red", "Parrot", "No"

"Dull", "Red", "Parrot", "No"

"Bright", "Blue", "Parrot", "Yes"

"Dull", "Blue", "Parrot", "No"

"Bright", "Red", "Cockatiel", "No"

"Dull", "Red", "Cockatiel", "No"

"Bright", "Blue", "Cockatiel", "No"

"Dull", "Blue", "Cockatiel", "Yes"

---

Comment: Is the order of your items fixed as 'brightness'/'colour'/'bird' (i.e you are actually looking at permutations), or do they change order (i.e. they are genuine combinations)?